# What is exchange web services better suited to do than office interop?

Tags: exchange-server, office-interop, exchangewebservices

I'm designing a winforms application that will run on users machines at my company.  One of its features will be to pull up upcoming appointments from the user's outlook account.  I'm wondering what the primary purposes for both office outlook interop and exchange web services are so that I can choose the best one for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Office interop primarily from within Outlook - for example, an Outlook Addin. In all other cases I would use EWS, primarily, because it removes the dependency on Outlook. If you use Outlook interop you need to care about the user having multiple outlook profiles and only working in the correct ones. You can use notifications (push, pull or streaming) to get notifications about changes in the users calendar so you don't have to constantly poll for changes.

You can pull appointments quite easily using the EWS Managed API:

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480
EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx